# Why is osk.exe reported as not existing and does not start?

Tags: windows-10, vb6, on-screen-keyboard

I see the following in the Explorer:

[image]

Now I try to run it using

```
Shell "C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe", vbNormalFocus
```

It fails, saying "File not found".

I am confused.

I call:

```
Shell "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\osk.exe", vbNormalFocus
```

The same error occurs.

When I use the following function to check for the existance, it also returns False.

```
Public Function FileExists(ByVal uPath As String) As Boolean

    Const NotFile = vbDirectory Or vbVolume
    
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = (GetAttr(uPath) And NotFile) = 0
    On Error GoTo -1
  
End Function
```

I am really baffled what might be going on here.

Comment: No idea what you're seeing, but since this is a system file, you shouldn't need to specify a path. Try just "osk.exe".

Comment: Perhaps this could help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227658/how-to-start-the-on-screen-keyboard-program-from-within-a-vb-6-legacy-applicatio

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a feature for 32 bit programs only. To 32 bit programs `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\osk.exe` is exactly the same file as `C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe` (but not to 64 bit) and both refer to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\osk.exe`.

So for a 32 bit program to access `System32` it needs to use a special name - `C:\Windows\SysNative\osk.exe`. Note the file redirector will look after it - there is no folder of that name.

Using that path on a 64 bit program will cause an error. Only 32 bit programs need it and only they can use it.